# Hierarchical query from two tables

Tags: oracle, hierarchical

Help me create a hierarchical query.
I have two table:

Table 1(dic_kgs)

```
KGS_ID    KGS_PARENT_ID    KGS_CODE
1                           A  
2              1            A0
3              1            A1
4                           B
```

and so on

Table 2(dic_kgs_strings)

```
KGS_ID    LANG_ID    KGS_NAME    KGS_ADD_INFO
1            1        Name1
2            1        Name2
3            1        Name3 
4            1        Name4
```

and so on.

I want to get result in the follow view:

```
A Name1
A0 Name2
A1 Name3
B Name4
```

I have writen only part of query:

```
select kgs_code
  from dic_kgs 
  start with dic_kgs.kgs_parent_id is null
      connect by prior dic_kgs.kgs_id = dic_kgs.kgs_parent_id;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Obviously DIC_KGS has a hierarchical structure but you're not using it in your query.  So what is the point you're trying to reach

Answer (score 0):

it not seems to be a hierarchical query what you need.

You can get the report using:

```
select 
   kgs_code, kgs_name 
from
   dic_kgs a join dic_kgs_strings b on (a.kgs_id = b.kgs_id)
```